# Java Container class, should I use all components as fields or just create them in constructor

Tags: java, components, containers

Which approach is better : say I have a class which extends a container instance and I want to add components to it should I use the components as fields or should I just create them in the constructor ?

Comment: Please elaborate. Generally, if you don't need to touch your components after adding them, use a constructor method; if they need to be accessible, for example, using a `mouseListener` to change the color of a `JPanel`, then use a field.

Comment: Ok gotcha, although I didn't understand why in the example you gave you need access to the panel ? if the panel has a mouseListener you can access it using e.getSource() no ?

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Let's say we use an ActionListener and a JButton to change the color; e.getSource() would return the button and we'd have no way to change the color of our JPanel unless it was stored in a variable. You use fields when you know you're going to be touching the component, but aren't sure if it'll always be accessible via e.getSource() or other similar means.

Comment: okay thanks for explaining ;) and we do the constructor method because a memory wise reason ?

Comment: Not really; variables don't have much overhead the way java works, but keeping an object alive does. Java keeps objects alive as long as they are being used (variables, fields, or objects contain a copy of it). Sometimes it doesn't make sense to have fields you don't need. Furthermore, it makes the code more readable. As the saying goes, perfection is achieved when you can remove nothing more.